# How come geom_bar is not plotting the y values present in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

The below code generates a table however, when I plot the table the resulting figure y-axis does not match the values present in the data frame.

```r
set.seed(1)
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3), rep('berrie', 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 5)
value <- append( abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15)), rep(NA,3))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
```

```
> data
     specie condition     value
1    sorgho    normal  9.396807
2    sorgho    stress  2.754650
3    sorgho  Nitrogen 12.534429
4    poacee    normal 23.929212
5    poacee    stress  4.942617
6    poacee  Nitrogen 12.307026
7    banana    normal  7.311436
8    banana    stress 11.074871
9    banana  Nitrogen  8.636720
10 triticum    normal  4.580826
11 triticum    stress 22.676718
12 triticum  Nitrogen  5.847649
13   berrie    normal        NA
14   berrie    stress        NA
15   berrie  Nitrogen        NA
```

```r
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: when I run your code , as above, I get proper results. Maybe try a new R session

Comment: The axis does not go to 60 on your end?

Comment: No, it goes up to a max of ~41, for poacee. I can post the image in an answer, below

Comment: Yes, can you please post your image and table?

Comment: So was there actually a problem with your code, or did you just misunderstand what you were plotting? If the latter, the question should probably be closed

Comment: I misunderstood what I was plotting. How do I close the question?

Comment: You probably can't delete it yourself now that you've accepted an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I run your code, as above, I get proper results, see below. Maybe try a new R session
[image]

My table:

```
    > data
     specie condition     value
1    sorgho    normal  9.396807
2    sorgho    stress  2.754650
3    sorgho  Nitrogen 12.534429
4    poacee    normal 23.929212
5    poacee    stress  4.942617
6    poacee  Nitrogen 12.307026
7    banana    normal  7.311436
8    banana    stress 11.074871
9    banana  Nitrogen  8.636720
10 triticum    normal  4.580826
11 triticum    stress 22.676718
12 triticum  Nitrogen  5.847649
13   berrie    normal        NA
14   berrie    stress        NA
15   berrie  Nitrogen        NA
```

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: I added it. I created it by simply running your code

Comment: I see the issue. My code is correct however, the graph I am trying to recreate in R is plotting averages, not sums. Thank you.